# Slider animation via keyboard not working (javascript and CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating an slider in JS (with angular) + CSS where the user should control via keyboard (left and right arrows). I made it simple as you can see below.

My code works this way: When the user clicks right, it adds one object in the begining of a array and delete the last one. When I click left, it makes the opposite.

```
slideEffect = function(dir) {
    if (dir == 'left') {
        lastChamp = champs[champs.length-1];
        champs.unshift(lastChamp);
        champs.pop();

    } else {
        firstChamp = champs[0];
        champs.push(firstChamp);
        champs.shift();

    }
}
```

The thing is. It works just fine when the user press "left arrow" but it goes wrong as soon as the user press right as you can see at: http://brunoornelas.com.br/test/pfc/

Does anyone have any clue on how to solve it the simplest way as possible and using Javascript? (I can't use jquery).

Thank you!

Comment: Could you include your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation is working, it's just that the `push` from first to last messes the effect. Ideal way would be to wait till the transition ends before pushing the element. Since we don't really have access to your actual code, it's a bit hard to give a proper solution, ideal solution would be to add a `transitionend` listener and `push` then. But quickly, you can try this in your slide right function, you'll see what needs to be done:

```
firstChamp = champs[0];
champs.shift();
setTimeout(function(){champs.push(firstChamp)},100);
```